# Move 1st column header to each row in certain width

Tags: sapui5

Whenever the browser size goes below `Desktop` width, I want my responsive table to hide the column headers and instead place them in the same row as its corresponding values for each entry.

Here is a visual example of what I want:

**Desktop width**
[image: Desktop width example]

**Below desktop width**
[image: Below desktop width example]

It seemed to me that the way to achieve this behavior was by adding...

```
minScreenWidth="desktop"
demandPopin="true"
```

...to the `<Column>` tag, but this **does not work for the 1st column**.

So my question is: How to (nicely) implement that behavior for the 1st column?

Here's my minimal example code (I changed the `Table.view.xml` of [this example](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableContextualWidthDynamic)):

```xml
<Table items="{/ProductCollection}">
  <columns>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Supplier" />
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Label text="{SupplierName}" />
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responsive table doesn't allow pushing all column headers to the items. From the [API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Table#overview):

> The `sap.m.Table` control requires at **least one visible `sap.m.Column`** in the columns aggregation, therefore applications must avoid configuring all columns to be shown in the pop-in. If such a conflict is detected, then the table **prevents** one column from moving to the pop-in.

You'll have to add at least one more column so that the 1st column does pop-in.

---

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1396